# Link Capacity and the Shannon-Hartley Theorem

Tags: communication, bandwidth, signal-to-noise

I'm reading Computer Networks: A Systems Approach by Peterson and Davies. One of the examples demonstrates the relationship between link capacity and the Shannon-Hartley Theorem.

We can find the channel capacity by the formula:

$$C =  B \log_2 \left( 1+\frac{S}{N} \right)$$

In the example of the book, they define bandwidth of the channel to be 3000Hz and the signal to noise ratio to be 30 dB, which they say would imply that S/N = 1000.

$$C =  3000 \times \log_2 (1001)$$

However, I don't understand how a signal to noise ratio of 30 dB is equivalent to 1000? How is this worked out? It's not explained in the example.

Comment: See [Decibel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) 30db is 1000, and it's explained there.

Comment: Oh I see, so its the power ratio - since decibels is logarithmic?

Comment: @gbulmer, with a couple more sentences of explanation, your comment could be an answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I am still new here. However, I thought ee.se was *not* about collecting answers that are already satisfied by trivial web searches, i.e. type one word into wikipedia and get a definitive answer. I was only being helpful in my comment. I had expected this question to be closed because it fell into that category of "very well-answered on the web with minimal effort already" question. Am I wrong?

Comment: @gbulmer, you're right it's not a great question. But it's borderline and hasn't gotten any close votes yet. So it's better we get an answer posted and accepted to keep the question from re-appearing on the front page.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson, dB measures the ratio of two power quantities. Since it's a ratio, it is a unitless number. For example, 30 dB gain in an amplifier means the output power is 1000 times as much as the input power. The (power) gain is 1000. Not pineapples, just 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formula, S/N is the power ratio of signal to noise.  If this ratio is expressed as 30 dB, then we have 10log(S/N) = 30 which results in a value for S/N of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Shannon: considers noise.
        Define the signal-to-noise ratio, SNR or S/N. Often measured in dB.
        Then:
                C = B log_2(SNR + 1)
        B = bandwidth
        C = max channel capacity

```
    Example: 3000Hz voice bandwidth, s/n = 30 dB. or a ratio of 1000.
    **C = 3000*log_2(1000) = 3000*10 = 30kbps**

Note that increasing signal strength does tend to increase noise as well.
Also, increasing bandwidth increases noise more or less in proportion.
    So: increasing B does lead to more thermal noise, and thus
    by Nyquist's formula SNR will decrease.
```

Comment: If this is just a copy / paste from the following course notes it's good to cite your references: http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~pld/courses/346/spr05/notes